# Check occurance of each digit in a number

Tags: php

Here is a code to check occurance of each digit in a number, which works fine unless and until the input number has one or more 0's in it. Can anybody point out the error?

```
$input_num = ($_POST["number_text"]);
$freq = array();
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $freq[$i] = 0;
}
for($k = 0; $k <= strlen($input_num); $k++) {                           
    $last = $input_num % 10;
    for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
        if($last == $j) {
            $freq[$j]++;
        }
    }
    $input_num /= 10;
}
print_r($freq);
```

Comment: FYI: to fill an array `$freq` is simplier to use `$freq = array_fill(0, 10, 0);`.

Comment: The inner `for` loop serves no purpose, and can be replace by `$freq[$last]++;`.

Comment: Something involving `array_count_values(str_split($_POST['number_text']))` would seem like a much saner approach…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

```
$input_num /= 10;
```

This isn't going to do quite what you expect. You're trying to remove the last digit of the string each time, but all you're doing is dividing by 10, resulting in a float. If you pass in `12345`, you won't end up with `1234`, but with `1234.5`

If you use

```
$input_num = substr($input_num, 0, -1);
```

then you should get what you want.

The other problem is in your loop condition:

```
$k <= strlen($input_num);
```

Because you're simultaneously increasing the size of `$k` and reducing the size of your string, you'll end up meeting in the middle, and only process half your string. You need to store the length up front, rather than calculating it on each iteration:

```
$length = strlen($input_num);
for($k = 0; $k < $length; $k++) {
```

As others have said in comments and answers, there are other optimisations you can make to this (removing the inner loop, for example), but this is still close to your original "algorithm". There are native ways of doing this in PHP much more concisely, but I assume you're deliberately steering clear of those.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to count each number?

```
$input_num = '00223555';
$freq = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $freq[$i] = substr_count($input_num, $i);
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3fa12c5a34aab87378b0a8c5b8097912c32fc036)